# What is a Class in python, what does it do, why is it needed?

Tags: python, class

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do I correctly understand what a class is?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2485360/do-i-correctly-understand-what-a-class-is)

Before you rant and rage and scream at me, understand that I tried searching everywhere, from google to this very site on what exactly a class in python is. I have found definitions of sorts, but have never been able to understand them fully. So here's the question. What is a class in python, what does it do, and why is it used?

Comment: Have you got any experience with object oriented programming at all? Or do you need it to be explained as well?

Comment: Classes in many languages (including Python) allow you to create your own new type of data.  They aren't needed as often as they are used.

Comment: Very little. I know most other computer terms, but OOP still baffles me. Its one of the reasons I asked here.

Comment: `I know more other computer terms` I highly doubt that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Class` (in any language) basically help in implementing [**OOPS**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming). By Following these principles, it becomes easier to maintain code & make changes etc.

I guess you start off by reading what OOPS is & then come back to Python.

Comment: down voter. Care to explain why you down voted?